# my drawRect function will not update

Tags: swift, view, viewcontroller, geometry, drawrect

I want the values for the colors of the circle to update when the variables(redd1,greenn1,bluee1) are changed by the steppers in my ViewController.  The original circle is drawn by drawRect.

```
var redd1 = 0.0;
var greenn1 = 0.0;
var bluee1 = 0.0;
override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
{
    let circle2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -25.0, y: 10.0, width: 100.0, height:100.0))
    circle2.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
    let startingColor2 = UIColor(red: (CGFloat(redd1))/255, green: (CGFloat (greenn1))/255, blue: (CGFloat(bluee1))/255, alpha: 1.0)
    circle2.backgroundColor = startingColor2;
    addSubview(circle2);
}
```

I tried creating a new function that draws a new circle on top of the old one.  It is called by the stepper.  The new function, updateColor(), receives the new value from the stepper.  This partially works because it prints out the correct new values, but never draws the new circle.

```
func updateColor()
{
    let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0;
    let startingColor = UIColor(red: (CGFloat(redd1))/255, green: (CGFloat(greenn1))/255, blue: (CGFloat(bluee1))/255, alpha: 1.0)
    circle.backgroundColor = startingColor;
    addSubview(circle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so good in Swift, but that's a simple way how i wood do it:

```
    var circle2: UIView

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        circle2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -25.0, y: 10.0, width: 100.0, height:100.0))
        circle2.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
        let startingColor2 = UIColor(red: (CGFloat(redd1))/255, green: (CGFloat (greenn1))/255, blue: (CGFloat(bluee1))/255, alpha: 1.0)
        circle2.backgroundColor = startingColor2;
        addSubview(circle2);

     }

    @IBAction valueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
        changeColor(color(the Color you want), Int(the Int value you want the color to change at))
    }

    func changeColor(color: UIColor, number: Int) {
        if stepper.value == number {
            circle2.backgroundColor = color
        }
    }
```

You have to create a IBAction for the stepper of the type value changed and call the method for every color and to it belonging Int in the IBAction for the stepper. So every time + or - on the stepper is pressed the IBAction calls the changeColor method and the changeColor method tests which color should be set to circle2.